# Spec$\mathbb{Z}$ in absolute geometry

Tags: field-with-one-element

What are the obstacles that prevent from defining Spec$\mathbb{Z}$ in absolute geometry? By absolute geometry I mean the geometry over the field with one element F1.

Comment: What do you mean by absolute geometry?

Comment: I am no expert, but the question seems rather broad. Is there a more focused version that you could ask, e.g. "why does *this* idea not work?"

Comment: The problem, as I understand it, is not in defining spec Z as an object over `$F_1$`.  There are actually quite a few definitions of $F_1$ and the first property that any putative definition must have is that it must map to Z.  The difficulty is in finding a setup where spec Z has various desired properties, such as admitting a nice compactification that behaves like a curve over $F_1$ (I think this is called the Deninger program).

Comment: The problem is probably not to define Spec Z in absolute geometry but to define the correct variant of absolute geometry where this question and some others will have an obvious and expected answer. 